# Eliminación de filas de una columna

Tags: sas

tengo un problema, tengo en SAS Guide una tabla con dos columnas, column1 y column2, necesito hacer lo siguiente, tomar el valor del primer registro de la column2 y buscarlo en todos los registros de la column1, una vez encontrados eliminarlos. Esto debe repetirse para cada valor de la columna 2 haciéndolo cada vez sobre la tabla con registros eliminados. Todos los valores son tipo texto. He intentado haciéndolo con un array que se actualiza después de cada iteración, pero no funciona en el 100% de los casos.

Comment: si tienes diferentes columnas porque eliminar el valor que las contiene, creo que deberías reemplazarlas con algo como `' '` entonces tu programa funcionaria correctamente, de no ser eso la causa porque habría error en algo que consiste en simples acciones como iterar, comparar y ejecutar determinada operacion.